# Call Laravel method on every pages before the page is loaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for a way to call a method and do a specific action before a page is loaded on every routes, and every method called on my project.

Except with View composers, is there any way to achieve this ? In my case I don't need to share any data to the view, it's just about instantiating a session value depending on some cases in my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try middlewares for achieving this. You can all middlewares in each route.